# $http/$q/promise Questions (in Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

I can't seem to wrap my head around when $q/$http should trigger the `onReject` block.

Let's say I have a basic call:

```
$http.get('/users')
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

If I get a `500 Internal Server Error` I'm going to end up in the `onSuccess` block.  From my meager understanding of promises I guess this seems correct because I technically did get a response?  The problem is an `onSuccess` block seems like the wrong place to have a bunch of

```
if(res.status >= 400) {
  return $q.reject('something went wrong: ' + res.status);
}
```

Just so that my `onReject` block will get run.  Is this the way it's supposed to work?  Do most people handle 400+ statuses in the `onSuccess` block or do they return a rejected promise to force the `onReject` block?  Am I missing a better way to handle this?

I tried doing this in an `httpInterceptor` but I couldn't find a way to return a rejected promise from here.

```
this.responseError = function(res) {
  if(res.status >= 400) {
    // do something
  }

  return res;
};
```

Comment: If there is a 400+ error code then your success block will not be hit. It will call your error handler

Comment: [Actually I'm pretty sure it doesn't](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/18a2e4fbfc44216c31bbcdf7705ca87c53e6f1fa/src/ng/http.js#L235-237).

Comment: Most likely you have an `httpInterceptor` for `responseError` - having an interceptor means that you "handled" the error (unless you explicitly `return $q.reject`), thus resulting in a success handler for `$http`

Comment: @NewDev ahhh that was it, thank you.  I didn't think about the implications of just doing `return res` in my `responseError` and how that would return a new, resolved promise rather than a rejected one.

Comment: Right.. exactly. As for this question - perhaps it would be better to delete it since the content of the question doesn't contain the reason for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success-block will not be hit. Try this and see that error-block will hit if error code > 300.

```
$http.get('/users').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle these in an interceptor instead of in your callback.

In your app.config you can configure your $httpProvider to something like this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            //do something 
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                //handle 401
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}]);
```